# UITabbar controller with other views ,not with main window in iphone using monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

Can we create tabbar controller with any window of application? I am having knowledge of creating with main window only ..which is landing page of application..Please any body solvemy prob..Thank u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add it to any other controllers but you can add it in MainWindow and make it appear and function in few ViewControllers only and not in the whole app. Add the UITabBarController in the AppDelegate and define it. Now, if you don't want tab bar from first in your app, you will have a navigation controller added as subView in the main window like this:

`[self.window addSubview:navController.view];`

`[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Now when you move to other controller and you wish to make the tab bar controller appear then you will have to remove the navigationController from the subView and add the Tab Bar controller to the subview. To do so make a separate method in AppDelegate:

```
 -(void)Load_tabBar
{
[self.navController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyWindow];
}
```

to remove the tab bar again do the reverse in another method:

```
  -(void)remove_tabBar
   {
    [self.tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
    [self.window addSubview:navController_initiale.view];
    [self.window makeKeyWindow];
   }
```

This will do the job for you!

Comment: Can you write this in monotouch i don't know object c actually.I can understand but how can we call these methods when we require?

Comment: Unfortunately I am sorry friend. I don't know monotouch. I write it in Objective C. And in Objective C you can call these methods by their respective calls as follows. Since they will be made in AppDelegate files, they will be called like this: `[appDelegate Load_tabBar];` & `[appDelegate remove_tabBar];` whenever they are necessary. Here appDelegate is the object of AppDelegate class.

Comment: Thank you Dip.I will try with my monotouch

Comment: Yes you've to place this code in you app delegate's .m file only as you'd have defined your UITabBarController there in MainWindow only. You'll have to write those methods there and then you can call them from any class you want.

Comment: Can we call these methods in required view with viewDidLoad() method ,is it correct?

Comment: But i am getting error...As Object reference not set to an instance of object.

Comment: I created that only one method which is remove navigation controller and add tabbar,and calling from another class which is moving from login to that page in that page it shows this error..And created an object for appDelegate in Next class to login and calling from there...

Comment: I hope you've defined the AppDelegate class' object correctly. In .h file as `SampleProgAppDelegate *appDelegate;` and .m file in `-(void) viewDidLoad:` method as `appDelegate=(SampleProgAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];` after that you can call the method to remove the NavigationController and the TabBarController. Also make sure that you've added the UITabBarController along with the NavigationController in the MainWindow and made all necessary connections. It works perfectly at my end.

Comment: Thank You Very much Dip..Thanks a lot but i have some problem that  i can solve it..

Comment: Actually in the tabbar ,is it necessary to first tab as Login Page?if i am setting like this its not getting error ,otherwise it willl arise error again what is problem?

Comment: No it is not necessary to set the first tab as Login Page but it is necessary to keep any one of the tabs selected when you add the TabBar. You can do that in AppDelegate's .m class by `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;`. I set the controllers for respective tabs from the MainWindow.xib file itself.

Comment: Ok,I got it.But we are navigating as loginPage to DealsPage, in that Deals page ,i need to show tabbar ,here i need to show Deals tab necessarily? or can show other page as First tab?

Comment: And In that deals page i am showing that page with tabcontroller successfully but ,in that page i need to set navigation bar as my customizable,like i need to remove back button ,and create custom back button..etc these are getting error..how can i solve it?

Comment: Thank u Dip,its amazing to learn from You,i am really getting satisfactory..Thanks a lot..

Comment: After removing Navigation bar ,can't we use navigation back button and etc related navigation bar?

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot use the back button or even make a custom button which will perform the push/pop operation because now we've UITabBarController in action. Now if you have 3 tabs for example and you wish to have navigation controller in all 3 tabs then that would be possible but that would be specific to the tab only. But you cannot have a back button performing Pop operation on the view where you're adding the TabBarController. Instead what you should do is put a back button in that view and call the method to add the NavigationController and remove the TabBarController.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add the UITabBarController on other view controllers (if that is what you mean by "any window"). It is meant to be the root controller of your app. If you add it to other controllers, it will not behave correctly.

Comment: But i need to show the tabbar in other windows not in main window.In the sense i am using navigation controller,tabbar controller,so i am showing tabbar in login window which is my landing page,but I need to show that tabbar in Deals page (one window) which is middle window of an application.How it is possible?can u help me?

Comment: Is it neccessory to show the login window as first tab in my tabbar controller?Because you are telling it should with root controller,my root controller is login window.

Comment: I understood your problem and I had worked this same problem earlier. I had UINavigationController in initial views where I had login, signup and other controllers and then once logged in I had to show tab bar. I used the two methods shown below to add and remove the Tab Bar Controller. It worked perfectly well. You'll have to add the UITabBarController along with the UINavigationController in the MainWindow itself and load the Navigation controller by default.